Instant noodles on Shabbat
There is a concept of Kli Sheini (a second cup) in which Halacha dictates that by taking boiling water from its source into an empty vessel and then pouring it into another vessel, the water is no longer considered to have the status of boiling as it can no longer “cook”. From my understanding that is why you’re allowed to make tea or coffee on Shabbat by using Kli Sheini.
My question is, items like instant noodles or instant couscous, which will “cook” even after Kli Sheini, would that be allowed and therefore you could cook on Shabbat, or perhaps for other reasons it would not be allowed?

Potential issues are kale bishul and when it comes to different modes of cooking. For example if something was fried or baked before shabbos to the put it in hot water on shabbos to heat it up would be cooking since the different mode of cooking would still be changing it.

So if something is kale bishul and would cook even after kli asiri it would not be allowed? Isn’t tea considered kale bishul though and yet it is allowed?

@Sht the Mishna Berura and aruch hashulchan forbid tea for that reason

I believe instant noodles are pre-cooked and just need rehydrating, and IIRC a prominent posek said in a shiur I attended that they would be permissible (I think he said do it in a kli shlishi just to be sure!)

Hasn't this been asked before?
